# Bash command prompt overwrites the current line

Tags: bash, prompt

My bash command prompt is:

```
\e[32;1m[\e[m\h.\u \e[33;1m\W\e[m\e[32;1m]\e[0;36m::\e[m
```

There must be something wrong with it, because on long lines, the current line is overwritten, instead of continuing on the next line.

I'm using OSX and bash 3.2.48

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every non printable sequence of characters must be enclosed between `\[` and `\]`:

```
'\[\e[32;1m\][\[\e[m\]\h.\u \[\e[33;1m\]\W\[\e[m\e[32;1m\]]\[\e[0;36m\]::\[\e[m\]'
```